# e_machine field in elf header

Tags: linux, binary, elf

In the elf header, there's 'e-machine' field. So my question is does it only specify the processor architecture the file can run on or it specifies the processor architecture that was used to make the elf file?

I have done some research and I've found that it specifies the architecture required for the file

Answer (score 1):

The job of ELF is to describe the executable, not where it came from. (that information would basically be useless; why would you care?)

Comment: Thanks for that. I also read somewhere that elf files are versatile, they can execute on multiple processors. so why would you specify the architecture in the first place?

Comment: you can have what is called FatELF, but that's actually a modification of the ELF standard.